# How to avoid page scroll-up when a link gets clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div which is half way down the page. After I click a button, I load an image in that div. What happens is, that the page scrolls all the way up. How to avoid this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to edit your click event. the simplest thing would be to `return false`. you could also [`preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) f.e. if you are using jquery.